# Bound datasheet subform find a record on the datasheet subform after a requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

The main form has a dropdown box with a list of companies.  When a company is selected the datasheet subform is populated with a list of clients.  The purpose of the datasheet subform is to make updates to the client information.  There is always 1200+ clients. Some of the changes require a popup modal form where a code is updated. I have to requery the datasheet subform to reflect the change.

So the problem is coming back to, for example, record 800 out of 1200 clients on the datasheet subform after the requery.

I have researched this for days on the internet.  I have tried everything from recordsets and bookmarks to you name it.  Whatever I could find on the internet.  I still cannot do a gotorecord after the requery.  Nothing seems to work.

I do save off the current record number but after the requery occurs I cannot do a gotorecord.  Does anyone have a solution?

Close event coming back out of the popup modal form:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
Dim rcdnum As Integer
Dim rs As dao.Recordset
Dim bkm As Variant

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("ManufacturerBuilderReview", dbOpenSnapshot)
rcdnum = Forms![Manufacturers]!RecNum
bkm = rs.Bookmark
If Me.ChangeFlg = 1 Then
    Forms![Manufacturers]![ManufacturerBuilderReview].Requery
End If
Forms![Manufacturers]![ManufacturerBuilderReview].SetFocus
Forms![Manufacturers]![ManufacturerBuilderReview]!BldrLst_trk_code.SetFocus
rs.FindFirst "BuilderID = '" & rs![BuilderID] & "'"
DoCmd.GoToControl "BldrLst_trk_code"

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check the limitation on the dropdown box.

Comment: Here is the code on the Close event coming back out of the popup modal form:

Comment: check the lined with `.SetFocus` and `DoCmd.GoToControl "BldrLst_trk_code"` something wrong there

Comment: Never mind.  I think I found a work-around.